# When is the Authorization header automatically sent by the browser?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, authorization

I am trying to know when is the `Authorization` header sent automatically by the browser and when not.

By reading several posts and experimenting, I found out that the browser only sends the credentials:

- When using `Basic` authentication, and only if the user input the username and password directly in the browser window (not, for example, if they were supplied in an XMLHttpRequest).
- When using `NTLM` authentication

I would like to find a document which states when the browser should and should not send the header automatically (something like a specs document). I am especially interested in `OAuth` and `Bearer` `Authorization` header types.

Answer (score 3):

Usually web browsers send Authorization header when it received 401 response. RFC 7235 "Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Authentication
" says:

> The "Authorization" header field allows a user agent to authenticate
>      itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
>      receiving a 401 (Unauthorized) response.

If you are finding specifications for HTTP authentication, see ["Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Authentication Scheme Registry"](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) which provides the list of authentication schemes and the references.

Comment: My question is about the "usually, but not necessarily" part. I'd like to find a document that states when. It looks like it's dependent on the authentication scheme.